# How to get expression using json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

My json array look like :-

```
Array 1 = [{"label":"1"},{"value":"6412"},{"label":"1"},{"value":"6413"},{"label":"2"},{"value":"6417"},{"label":"3"},{"value":"6418"},{"label":"3"},{"value":"6419"}];
```

Now i want result as following way :-

```
result = ["#1|6412,6413","#2|6417","#3|6418,6419"];
```

Comment: What have you tried? And you might want to break down the expected result - it took me a while to figure it out

Comment: sorry but i'd edit my question now can you check it out now ?

Comment: JSON structure is very inconvenient to deal with. If it's possible, you'd better change it to `[{label:1, values:[6412, 6413]}, ...]`.

Comment: ok dfsq can you edit structure with yourself and get result ?

Comment: well not very handsome json but can be edited

Comment: can you pls.give one demo with plnkr ?

Comment: I understand you want as a result an array like:

[ "#1" : "value for 1", "#2": "values for 2] or do you want just a string as a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, of course I would strong advise you to change your json structure.

```
var arr = [{"label":"1"},{"value":"6412"},{"label":"1"},{"value":"6413"},{"label":"2"},{"value":"6417"},{"label":"3"},{"value":"6418"},{"label":"3"},{"value":"6419"}];

var formatted = [];

for (i=0;i<arr.length;i+=2)
{
    var label = "#" + arr[i].label;
    var value =arr[i+1].value
    if (formatted[label] == null) 
        formatted[label] = value;
    else               
        formatted[label] += ", " +value;
}

console.log(formatted);
```

Edited: now it returns an array like: `[#1: "6412, 6413", #2: "6417", #3: "6418, 6419"]`

https://jsfiddle.net/4zr0q8j3/

Comment: Thanks @Balder for your reply but if i take 3,4 same keys using dynamic array as json format then your above code isn't works correctly ...

Comment: sorry @Balder That's my mistake it's working fine for me, now can you give solution to remove space which added after last element ..Thanks in advance ..

Comment: just edited it to has comma separator without ending space

Comment: Ohhh .. This is what i am expecting .. Thanks ..! :)

Answer (score 0):

Array arr have your answer

*Man changing your question make double effort

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        //var json = '{"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4"}';
        // result = ["#1|6412,6413#2|6417#3|6418,6419"];
        var json = '[{"label":"1"},{"value":"6412"},{"label":"1"},{"value":"6413"},{"label":"2"},{"value":"6417"},{"label":"3"},{"value":"6418"},{"label":"3"},{"value":"6419"}]';

        var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
        var rahul='';
        var rahul_old;
        var arr = [];

        for(var x in parsed){
        //  alert(parsed[x]);

            for(var x2 in parsed[x]){

                if(x2=='label'){
                        if(parseInt(rahul_old)==parseInt(parsed[x][x2])){
                            rahul+=",";

                        }else{
                            if(rahul.trim()!=''){
                            //  alert(rahul);
                                arr.push(rahul);
                                rahul='';
                            }

                            rahul+=("#"+parsed[x][x2]+"|");
                        }
                    rahul_old=parseInt(parsed[x][x2]);
                }else if(x2=='value'){
                    rahul+=parsed[x][x2];

                }
            }


        }
        if(rahul.trim()!=''){
                                alert(rahul);
                            //  arr.push(rahul);
                                rahul='';
                            }
                            //arr have you result
                            alert(arr.length);



        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your json array increase more dimension then extra for loop needs. but more elements increase instead of dimension it will work perfectly. hope it will help you and please don't forget to give a upvote

Answer (score -1):

Change your json format as below:

```
var array = [
{
    "label": "1",
    "value": [
        6412,
        6413
    ]
},
{
    "label": "2",
    "value": [
        6417
    ]
},
{
    "label": "3",
    "value": [
        6418,
        6419
    ]
}
];

var result = [];
for(i in array){

  var temp = "#"+array[i].label+"|"+array[i].value.join();
  result.push(temp);

}
console.log(result);  // output is ["#1|6412,6413", "#2|6417", "#3|6418,6419"]
```

Comment: obviously... if you change the json is easier, but this is not what he asked for

Comment: Mr. balder from his json. to build this format(["#1|6412,6413", "#2|6417", "#3|6418,6419"]) is not possible at all in any language. because no where label and value linked

Comment: How do you identify which value is related to which label?

Comment: its just a key - value array but instead of using a good key-value array he is using 2 elements in the array, one for key, next for value. Of course is a bad json, but it can be done, sometimes you dont have the chance of changing the json format, for example while consuming a WS

Comment: That you provided code is as imagination only. may be value next to label is not related that label. In that case issue will come. I think that's not a good practice.